# how to put wallet contents in PHP?

Tags: php, joomla3.0, wavesplatform

I am trying to integrate waves tokens in my website, it runs on joomla, and I know a bit about php.
I successfully integrate my token's ticker using your api.

- Now I would like to link my users to their wallet, so thet can see their balance directly on my site (balance in Bastion token).
- I would use their wallet adress also to show a top 10 holder list, keeping their adress hidden if they want
- Finally if I find a good documentation, I could try to integrate transfer from-to their wallet, and even automate coin distribution, but that's not for tomorrow.

My issue? I use php, I would like to know if someone could help me or if there exist and exhaustive documentation about it

Big thanks to all helpers.

Wanna see my current integration ? : https://www.itharagaian.net/main/index.php/bastion-token/getting-bastion-tokens

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: How should I know, the support guys from Waveplateform asked me to post my question here

Comment: I would never, under any circumstances, use Joomla to handle cryptocurrencies. Checking a balance, sure, but anything involving transfers or anything else with the private keys? Nooooope.

Comment: I do agree, the joomla is only for the front end site, anything sending data to the chain would be in separate php file, probably another domain also, especially for the sql requests as joomla uses tons of requests already

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to do.

Balance =

```
$curl = curl_init();

$opts = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://nodes.wavesplatform.com/assets/balance/3PC1NwcrvR9EwDCZ4na2q1RrUY21M5RMg7W/9dmvLmq8iK4aXTHk21Fdi3Tjf2XJUHUoBokvS7zsG7Sn',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$balance= json_decode($response, true);

echo "This account has ";
echo $balance[balance]/100000000;
echo "Bastion Tokens";
?>
```

And list of wallets

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$opts = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://nodes.wavesplatform.com/assets/9dmvLmq8iK4aXTHk21Fdi3Tjf2XJUHUoBokvS7zsG7Sn/distribution',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$balance= json_decode($response, true);
echo "<br>";

echo "<table><tr><th>NBR</th>< th>WALLET</th><th>VALUE</th></tr>";
foreach ($balance as $address => $amount) {
    $i=$i+1;

   echo "<tr><td>";
    echo  $i;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $address;
    $wallet[$i] = $address;
    echo " </td><td>";
    echo round($amount/100000000);
    $value[$i]= round($amount/100000000);
    echo "  Bastion</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";




?>
```